# Control-space not working in Notepad++

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, intellisense, notepad++

I've been using Notepad++ forever but must have done something to stop Control + Spacebar from opening the intellisense (auto complete) of whatever language I am busy with. Anyone know what might be causing this?

Comment: Hover over "Edit" then hover over "Auto-Completion" next to "Function Completion" it should state the assigned shortcut. Can you tell me what this is. (If it's ctrl + Spacebar then the issue lies with your keyboard config via windows.)

Comment: Thanks guys. Installed latest version and all's good now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just re-installed Notepad++ and it worked. Thanks for all the suggestions though.

Answer (score 1):

Check the "Shortcut Mapper" on the "Settings" menu

"Function Completion" should be mapped to "Ctrl + Space"